# Why is @FacesConverter(forClass=String.class) not working

Tags: jsf-2

I followed the example here: [Why does <h:inputText required="true"> allow blank spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326398/why-does-hinputtext-required-true-allow-blank-spaces) to create a "Global" converter to trim all input fields. However, the converter is not being invoked when input fields are submitted.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=String.class) 
... 
<p:inputText value="#{controller.inputValue}"/>
```

but when I change to:

```
@FacesConverter("StringTrimmer") 
... 
<p:inputText value="#{controller.inputValue}" converter="StringTrimmer"/>
```

it works.

Using Mojarra 2.1.7 and PrimeFaces 3.2

Comment: Is the `inputValue` really of type `String`?

Comment: That was it.. (Thought it was String-- it was not). Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This didnt work because the inputValue was not actually of type String. Once changed to type String-- it worked.

Answer (score 3):

A converter with a `forClass` will only be invoked whenever the type of the property is an instance of the specified class. In your particular case, that can only mean that the `#{controller.inputValue}` is **not** of type `String`.

Comment: i tried it directly with #{inputValue} instead of #{controller.inputValue}, with 'inputvalue' declared as a managedbean within the request scope. it didn't work. should it been always declared as property of a wrapper bean like #{controller.inputValue} ?

Answer (score 1):

If you checked that the bound variable is of type String and the converter still doesn't get called, you may also check the following:

- If the input component is encapsulated inside a composite component, you may have [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4943490/840977). In that case, converters would not be called correctly, resulting in your custom method to be never reached. Calling the converter explicitly on the input component solves this.
- If you add both `value="someName"` and `forClass="someClass"` to the `@FacesConverter` annotation, the forClass attribute will be ignored.  This has been [reported here](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1650).